# Facial processing in android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-camera

I'm developping an android app that relies highly on camera and i have to integrate facial processing of emotions for example. I don't know where to start ?
I found a couple of SDK like snapdragon but i can't seem to figure out how to use them. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google provides the [Mobile Vision API](https://developers.google.com/vision/) that helps with facial processing. You can read more about the facial processing features [here](https://developers.google.com/vision/face-detection-concepts).

If you want a sample application using that API you can look [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker).